# BinaryWriter.BaseStream.Position wrong?

Tags: c#

```
BinaryWriter bw;
while(bw.BaseStream.Position < 192137)
bw.Write((byte) 0);
```

At the end, `bw.BaseStream.Position` equals 192152 (not 192137!). And the file size is 192 104 bytes. How is this possible?

Comment: Is the stream opened for append? Have you checked the `Position` before you start writing? Did you `close` the stream?

Comment: The stream is made from a File.Create(), and the Position is less than 192137 before. It is indeed closed at the end.

Answer (score 1):

BinaryWriter buffers the data before writing it to the underlying Stream.

If you want to write 192137 bytes, write 192137 bytes to the BinaryWriter  instead of waiting until 192137 bytes have been written to the underlying Stream:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 192137; i++)
{
    bw.Write((byte) 0);
}
```

*Rule of thumb:* Use Stream or BinaryWriter, but don't use them both. (I.e., if you use a BinaryWriter, don't access the BaseStream.)

Comment: But I don't want to write 192137 bytes - I just want to fill the rest of the file with zeros until it's 192137 bytes long.

Comment: Then you have to keep attack of the number of bytes you have already written using BinaryWriter. Or don't use BinaryWriter.

Comment: Then `Flush()`, check the position, calculate the remaining bytes, and write that amount in a loop. Don't check the position after every byte.